# How to increment value in mysql database column from user defined value using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I have a DB table "mtoken" where I have a column "sbonus" if I add any new row to this table means the initial value of "sbonus" is set to be "0". I'll assign values to "sbonus" through user-defined input Box and at any case, the value of "sbonus" should not go more than 5000.

My Requirement is to Add the value in "Sbonus" + "User-defined value from the Input box" then check condition whether the value is lesser than 5000 or not and if lesser update the added final value to the "sbonus". If not return "Value Exceeded"

Initially, the value given is added with 0 and db set to the given value. Now existing rows have some values("100") in Column "sbonus" if I add a new row to "mtoken" the "sbonus"column has "0" value.

Now I am giving a value "200" from the user-defined input box. It should be like,
Existing Row Sbonus Value
100+200 = 300

New Row Sbonus Value,
0+200 = 200

When I am using below code all row "sbonus" value is set to 200. Please find below code and pls help me to resolve it.

The user-defined input value is given as 200 means,

Existing Row Sbonus Value is 100

New Row Sbonus Value is 0

Check condition the output value should be lesser than 5000.

I need output as

The existing row "sbonus" should be like,

100 + 200 = 300

New row "Sbonus" value should be like,

0+200 = 200

```
 <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <form method="post" action="add_sbonus.php">    
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Surprise Bonus Per Token</label>
                            <input type="number" name="sbonus" class="form-control" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="submit" name="s_bonus" class="btn btn-primary" value="SurpriseBonus">
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['s_bonus'])){
        $sbonus = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['sbonus']);
            if($sbonus!=''){
                $query = mysqli_query($con, "select sbonus from mtoken where status='Selled'");
                while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
                $dbonus = $row['sbonus'];
                $nbonus = $dbonus + $sbonus;
                    if($nbonus<=5000){
                        $sqlupdate = mysqli_query($con,"update mtoken set sbonus='$nbonus' where status='Selled'");
                            if(!$sqlupdate) {
                                echo mysqli_error($con);
                                echo '  <script>
                                            alert("Bonus NOT Updated");
                                        </script>';
                                }
                    }
                    if($nbonus>5000){
                     echo '<script>
                                alert("Value Exceeded");
                                window.location.assign("sbonus.php");
                            </script>';
                    }
                }   
            }else{
                    echo '<script>
                                alert("Please fill all the fields");
                            </script>';
                }

        echo '<script>
                alert("Surprise Bonus Added To Tokens");
                window.location.assign("sbonus.php");
            </script>';
    }
    ?>
```

[DB-with-Initial Value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRK8k.png)

[DB-with-User-Defined + Initial Value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLHc9.png)

[Existing Rows and New Added Rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNT8k.png)

[Error-Both existing row and new row showing same value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2kDi.png)

Comment: Don't put your code as links to images. Put your code as plain text

Comment: @nacho I have pasted the code in Plain Text. Pls help to resolve it.

Comment: @NJInamdar I have pasted the code in Plain Text. Pls help to resolve it.

Comment: You have done it again, don't put links to images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

syntax error

```
mysqli_query($con,"update mtoken set sbonus='$nbonus' where id = $row['id']");
```

Changes Made

```
$rid = $row['id'];

mysqli_query($con,"update mtoken set sbonus='$nbonus' where id = '$rid'");
```

Answer (score 0):

`where status='Selled'` will update **all** rows which have that value in the status column. So every time you run that it will update all the rows. What you end up with depends on which row is the last to be returned from your SELECT statement.

If you want to update a **specific** single row then you need to add something in the `where` clause which identifies that exact row. The `id` would be the obvious thing to use, since it's unique.

For this you need to change your two query lines:

```
mysqli_query($con, "select id, sbonus from mtoken where status='Selled'");
```

and

```
mysqli_query($con,"update mtoken set sbonus='$nbonus' where id = $row['id']");
```

---

N.B. A linguistic side note: In English, "selled" is not a word. "sell" has a non-standard past tense version, which is "sold". So if you want to write your status in English, you should write "sold" instead of "selled". See [here](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/sold).

Comment: Thank you its Worked for me with Simple Changes.